# Is there a shortcut for git branch name?

Tags: git

I tend to have long branch names for git (e.g., step110_create_search_engine_to_replace_google).

How should I refer to it simply as step110 in checkout/commit statements?

Comment: Have you activated the `contrib/complete/git-completion.bash` git autocompletion rules? You should be able to type `git checkout step110<tab>` and have your shell auto-complete the branch name.

Comment: Hi Simont, it seems to be the answer I am looking for. Could you please tell me how to activate git-completion and move it to answer, so that I can accept it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're on a Unix-like system (Linux, Mac OS X, perhaps others), there's the `contrib/complete/git-completion.bash` bash auto-complete ruleset, which will let you auto-complete git commands (you can type `git checkout step110<tab>` and your shell will autocomplete the branch-name.

To activate this:

- If you've got the git source, in `contrib/complete/` there's a file `git-completion.bash`. Put that somewhere safe (like `~/.git-completion`), and then add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file: `source ~/.git-completion`. Either restart your shell session or run `source ~/.git-completion` to get it running in the current shell session.
- If you *dont* have the git source, you can get the script from [here](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) (github.com). Then follow the same instructions as above.

If you're lucky enough to be using `zsh` instead of `bash`, I know that [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) has git autocompletion plugins (I'm not sure how to activate them without `oh-my-zsh`).

Sources:

- [mbuttu.wordpress.com](http://mbuttu.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/git-autocomplete-for-bash-shells/)
- [codethatmatters.com](http://www.codethatmatters.com/2010/01/git-autocomplete-in-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 14):

Here is how I installed it on OS X...

Check if it's on your local system first. It seems MacPorts and Homebrew download it for you.

```
$ find / -name "git-completion.bash"
```

Otherwise, download it...

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -O ~/.git-completion
```

If you don't have `wget`, you can install it easily with [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/) or use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

```
$ vim ~/.profile
```

...or your editor of choice.

Then add...

```
source ~/.git-completion
```

If your autocompletion doesn't work automatically...

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

...and then you have Git autocompletion.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't know about this, but it's soooooo nice. Git should do this out of the box.

Comment: On OSX, if you installed git via MacPort, you will have the script at this location: /opt/local//share/doc/git-core/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Comment: It also looks like brew will put it somewhere already for you too :)

Comment: @jhoff how should git do this out of the box? this is a bash setting, and besides not everybody is using bash as a shell.

Answer (score 4):

Try this alias:

```
cb = "!checkoutbranch() { local branches=`git branch | grep -i $1 | tr -d '* '`; if [[ `echo \"$branches\" | wc -l | tr -d ' '` != 1 ]]; then echo \"Matched multiple branches:\"; git branch | grep --color -i $1; exit 1; fi; git checkout $branches; }; checkoutbranch"
```

Checkout the `develop` branch:

```
git cb dev
```

---- edit ----

A better version: https://gist.github.com/iwill/88f5835bfc4e58aa1a88

Comment: Very, very cool. And works like a charm! Just pass it any substring in branch name, and it will be chosen for you. Great idea. That's what I was looking for - tab completion is too slow and clunky for me.

Comment: Ok,I wil try it in a few hours when at work. So far using this alias I have two comments:
1. I wanted to substitute git checkout for it (with typical alias g co), unfortunately it doesn't support commits and files. You know, git allows to do git co <commit id> and git co <filename to revert from index>.
2. Overall, I think that having this functionality in more places where you can pass branchname would be awesome.

Comment: Ehh, 5 min limitation for editing comment. 1. continue: And there's also HEAD. So for those special cases, the script would have to pass work to the typical checkout. Doing it manually is probably not possible, but perhaps there's some git plumbing function which you pass string, and it returns the type of git object: branch, commit or path. Then we could have this git co on steroids.

Comment: Sorry, it is just cb - checkout branch, but not xb, I use co and other git command for the other features.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. If I have time I will try to make it more universal. One additonal note: git cb won't work on branch names that were just fetched. That's because git won't treat them as local. And adding -a to git branch in the alias won't help, as upon checkout you won't be on branch, but on single commit. I'm sure there's way to fix it in some way, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

[`git symbolic-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref.html) may help if you are too lazy to even press a <kbd>TAB</kbd>. You can create an alias to the branch.

```sh
$ # Define short name 's1'
$ git symbolic-ref refs/heads/s1 refs/heads/step110_create_search_engine_to_replace_google
$
$ # You can use short name 's1' afterwards
$ git reset --hard s1
$ git checkout -b s1-experiment s1
$
$ # Remove the short name (don't use branch -d here or the original branch gets deleted!)
$ git symbolic-ref -d refs/heads/s1
```

Remote branches can be referred in the same manner to save typing `remote/`<kbd>TAB</kbd>. (In this case, I recommend to prefix with `refs/tags/` instead of `refs/heads/` to prevent moving the remote ref accidentally)

```sh
$ git symbolic-ref refs/tags/base refs/remotes/github/a-very-long-named-remote-branch
$ git rebase -i base
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. We have long branch names and "links" to branches is what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that this file usually already comes with git.  You don't need to download it again. You just need to locate it and run it.

On my system (Centos OS) the following steps works:

```
$ locate completion.bash
/usr/share/doc/git-1.7.4.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
$ source /usr/share/doc/git-1.7.4.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
```

Obvioiusly as pointed out already it's better to add this line to your .bashrc file in your home directory, so that you don't need to repeat it everytime you open a new shell.

In my case I would add the last command to my .bashrc file

```
source /usr/share/doc/git-1.7.4.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
```

Answer (score 0):

On Unix-like systems you can.

```
git branch | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | tr -d '\n'
```